# JavaScript window location delay

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am brand new to JavaScript, and I have this code which leads to 1 of 3 web sites.
The code can be seen here:
[http://imgur.com/Z7YHGjt](https://imgur.com/Z7YHGjt).
I have no WiFi on my PC so I was unable to take a proper screenshot and upload it. Sorry.
I want it to be so the page is shown for 2 or 3 seconds, before it redirects.
I tried to Google it, but was unable to find a fix for my problem.
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

    // Put your code here.
    var r = Math.random();
    // ...

}, 3000);
```